# c# datatable by the order of another list

Tags: c#, datatable

i have a list of strings:

```
List<string> batchaddresses = new List<string>();
```

here are the contents of it:

```
17055
17064
18045
23564
11111
24200
    ...
    ...
```

i have a data table that looks like this:

```
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
```

here are the contents (there are three columns)

```
15 G231796 17024
2 G238540 17024
6 G238546 17024
12 G238547 17024
81 G238549 17024
9 BLANK0048 17024
12 BLANK0047 17024
34 BLANK0045 17024
43 BLANK0046 17024
63 BLANK0042 17024
78 BLANK0044 17024
85 BLANK0041 17024
96 BLANK0043 17024
46 AA102461 17025
19 AA10589 17025
86 AA10590 17025
22 AA10591 17025
43 AA19665 17025
44 AA19668 17025
```

i need to be able to sort the datatable by the third column **according to its order in the batchaddresses list**

how would i do this? thank you so much for any advice or guidance

Comment: @anthony why did you delete yoru answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var query =
    from b in batchaddresses
    join r in myTable.AsEnumerable() on b equals r.Field<String>("ThirdColumn")
    select r;

var orderedTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

*Added:* It is worth mentioning that the [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) method is only available on `IEnumerable<DataRow>` types.

*Edited*: no orderby needed

Comment: @alex i need it not to be sorted by alpha or numeric order i need it to be sorted exactly by the order of strings in batchaddresses. so if the first string is 110 and the second one is 99 that is the order i want to keep for the datatable

Comment: @Alex, good solution, I didn't realize the `CopyToDataTable` extension method existed. Two things I would advise is to first eliminate the orderby line, as it is invalid, and then to change the order of your enumerables, use the list first and join to the table, not the other way around. By doing that, it should preserve the order of the list, not the order of the table.

Comment: @JOE, @Anthony: fixed to meet requirements.

Comment: @Joe, because Alex showed me something I didn't realize existed, making my answer overkill as long as he corrected small parts here (and he has).

Comment: Very well done, this is the kind of (simple) example that show LINQ in all its glory!

Comment: im sorry! this works great. thank you so much for your guys' help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this solution, but I would add a column to dt and populate it with the position of each row's third column in batchaddresses. Then it's a simple matter of calling `Select` with the added row in the sort order argument.

Comment: thank u very much can you show me how u would code the select?

Comment: plus - this part is difficult to do I would add a column to dt and populate it with the position of each row's third column in batchaddresses.

Comment: Well, that's the easy part! Here you go: `var rows = dt.Select("<list the column you want>", "<added column> <sort direction>");`

Comment: sorry can u be more explicit please

Comment: Look at Alex Bagnolini answer, much better than mine. I didn't thought about using LINQ for that!

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the overload of Select to get the index of each item:

```
var table = batchaddresses.Select((xx,ii) => new { Value = xx, Order = ii })
                .Join(dataTable.AsEnumerable(),
                      (outer) => outer.Value,
                      (inner) => inner.Field<string>("ThirdColumn"),
                      (outer, inner) => new { Order = outer.Order, Row = inner })
                .OrderBy(xx => xx.Order)
                .Select(xx => xx.Row)
                .CopyToDataTable();
```